# Jasmine spy on function exported with no parent object and imported using ES6 in NODE

Tags: node.js, ecmascript-6, jasmine

Having done a lot of research I cannot find a way to mock functions that are exported with no parent object. For example I'm trying to mock functions exported the following way:

```
module.exports = function thing(event) {};
```

OR in ES6

```
export function thing(event) {};
```

When importing these into a test file I try importing like this:

```
import {thing} from 'emvio-util-responses;  


//call some function that calls thing()

spyOn(???, 'thing').and.returnValue({});
expect(???.thing).toHaveBeenCalled();
```

I have tried many ways of accomplishing this but the mock is not called.
Some suggest importing * and providing an alias as a parent object. like this:

```
import * as SomeObj from 'emvio-util-responses;  


//call some function that calls thing()

spyOn(SomeObj , 'thing').and.returnValue({});
expect(SomeObj .thing).toHaveBeenCalled();
```

This doesn't work.

Others suggest using the window object

```
spyOn(window, 'thing').and.returnValue({});
```

But I'm in node :(.

Answer (score 0):

When you use es6 modules instead CommonJS all exports are named so you may use:

```
export default (event) => {}
```

and then import & spy as

```
import * as SomeObj from 'emvio-util-responses'

...
beforeEach(() => {
   spyOn(someObj, 'default')
});
```